# ChatGPT colors in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I change colors in [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) in plugin ChatGPT? It’s too dark.

My chat

[image: My chat]

Options

[image: Options]

Comment: why not ask chatgpt how it works?

Comment: Funny. It doesn't know.

Answer (score 0):

Change to the light theme in IDEA.    Look under Settings->Appearance:

[image]

Comment: No result. the chat is still dark. I would like to leave it dark, just change the color of the letters.